# Is there any difference in the architecture of a neural net for regression (time series prediction) and for classification?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, classification, non-linear-regression

Is there any difference in the architecture of a neural net for regression (time series prediction) and for classification?

I did some regression testing but I get quite bad results.

I'm currently using a basic feed forward net, with one hidden layer with 2 to 4 neurons, `tanh` activation function and momentum.

Comment: Are you getting bad results both in regression and in classification? Bad in regression and good in classification? Or the other way around? It could depend on the data as well

Comment: I just tested classification with XOR problem and got good results. But I used the logistic function for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on a lot of factors :

1. In case of classification you can have a binary classification problem (where you want to discriminate between two classes) or multinomial classification problem. In both cases you could use different architectures for achieving the goal of the best data modeling.
2. In case of sequence regression - you could also use loads of different architectures - starting from normal feedforward network which receives one series as input and returns second as output to a lot different recurent architectures.

So the question you asked is similiar to : are tools useful for building cars different from tools useful for building bridges - it's too ambiguous and you have to specify more details.

Comment: Sorry, my question was not precise. I heard that RBF Nets perform better in regression tasks than MLPs do and I've also heard that RNNs (with Gates) are superior over MLPs in regression tasks. I should have changed it in "Which Neural Network Architecture performs best in Time Series Prediction" and asked for the specific benefeits between the architectures.